# Can you call Html->scriptBlock() from controller beforeFilter() function in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I want to insert a block of JavaScript in all pages, and though the best way to do it is in beforeFilter function since this is executed all the times and it will be automatically included in $scripts_for_layout of all templates.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure why the question was down voted.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just putting it in the layout file ?

```
<head>
....
<?php
echo $this->Html->script('my_js_file');
?>
...
</head>
```

By the way, `Html` is a helper, so it should not be used in controllers.

Comment: because I have several layout files and the best way to not duplicating code is adding it in $scripts_for_layout.